# Is there a way to add MicroQR barcodes as an AVMetadataObject.ObjectType?

Tags: ios, swift, barcode

I need to scan MicroQR barcodes using the camera on iOS devices. Does anyone know of a native way to add the type? For example my constant for the builtins looks like so: Oh yeah I'm using Swift

```
let supportedCodeTypes = [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.upce, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39,
                      AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39Mod43, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code93,
                      AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code128, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean8,
                      AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean13, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.aztec,
                      AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.pdf417, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.itf14,
                      AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.dataMatrix, AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.interleaved2of5,
                      AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr]
```

I'm thinking that I might be able to implement it this way:

```
 let microqr = AVMetadataObject.ObjectType(rawValue: String)
```

Then I would be able to add it to my array, but I don't know what to place as the string for the rawValue:. Of course I am not even sure if this would work. I would really appreciate a push in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: iOS doesn't support microQR code for now. I think they will support it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No — the recognition engine(s) for `AVCaptureMetadataOutput` are in system software or hardware, and Apple provides no API for plugging in your own engine for new object types.

You're correct that it is possible to construct a value of type `AVMetadataObject.ObjectType` using the `init(rawValue: String)` initializer and any arbitrary string. However, the AVCapture system can act only on the object types it knows — other values of the `AVMetadataObject.ObjectType` type are meaningless to API that use that type. (I'm not sure whether unknown `ObjectType` values will be ignored by such API or raise an error, but it's easy to check...)

In other words, calling `AVMetadataObject.ObjectType(rawValue: "someNewBarcodeStandard")` doesn't teach AVCapture how to recognize that kind of barcode any more than `AVMetadataObject.ObjectType(rawValue: "")` teaches it how to recognize fish.

By the way, Swift type inference means you don't have to write out every type/constant name longhand:

```
let supportedCodeTypes: [AVMetadataObject.ObjectType] = [.upce, .code39,
                  .code39Mod43, .code93,
                  .code128, .ean8,
                  .ean13, .aztec,
                  .pdf417, .itf14,
                  .dataMatrix, .interleaved2of5,
                  .qr]
```

Comment: I was trying to be thorough I've had people be pretty rough when  I asked questions here before. Ok so I am not going to get anywhere with my idea. Is there a way to do it? Maybe another Library I should look into? and not LeadTools, my boss already said he won't pay for it.

Comment: Yes, you will need some other library that can process the raw image and recognise the barcodes.  Unfortunately, recommending libraries is off-topic for SO